# Spring Boot Not Finding Any Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller

Hello i've tried to create a simple controller and put it in the same package with the main class but it looks like it's not finding it.Basically, when i run the app it's not mapping the endpoint.
I just can't figure out what is wrong with it.
Here is the code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestProject1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestProject1Application.class, args);
    }
}


package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "HELLO";
    }

}
```

Project Structure and Console:
[image: ProjectStructure]

[image]

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestProject-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: post your pom.xml

Comment: I've added my pom.xml

Comment: Use JDK instead of JRE. Use @GetMapping("/hello") instead of @RequestMapping. Your config is OK, your pom too.

Answer (score 0):

Although in your log, I do not see 'ServletRegistrationBean' getting initialized, I find no issue with your configuration. Try execute the Spring boot app again & you should be able to invoke the *HomeController* via 'localhost:8080/hello'.

Comment: I've tried that and it would give me http not found 404 error :( I think i'm just going to do a clean installation of my os and see if that would change anything